# Platform-specific RUN statements in Dockerfile

Tags: c#, linux, docker, powershell, ubuntu

I have an ASP.NET Core application running in Docker on my Raspberry Pi (`arm64`). This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj", "src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/"]
COPY ["src/ScreenshotCreator.Logic/ScreenshotCreator.Logic.csproj", "src/ScreenshotCreator.Logic/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/ScreenshotCreator.Api"
RUN dotnet build "ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget libssl1.1 libunwind8
RUN mkdir -p /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
RUN wget -O /tmp/powershell.tar.gz https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.6/powershell-7.2.6-linux-arm64.tar.gz
RUN tar zxf /tmp/powershell.tar.gz -C /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
RUN chmod +x /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
RUN ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh
RUN rm /tmp/powershell.tar.gz
RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1", "install", "chromium"]
RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1", "install-deps", "chromium"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScreenshotCreator.Api.dll"]
```

When trying to build and run this Docker container on my Windows machine (`amd64`, Docker via WSL2 (Ubuntu)), it fails because a) the base image is not correct and b) the bunch of `RUN` statements for installing PowerShell at the end have to look different depending on the platform:

```bash
# Install PWSH on Raspberry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-raspbian?view=powershell-7.3#install-on-raspberry-pi-os
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install '^libssl1.0.[0-9]$' libunwind8 -y
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.3.4/powershell-7.3.4-linux-arm64.tar.gz
mkdir ~/powershell
tar -xvf ./powershell-7.3.4-linux-arm32.tar.gz -C ~/powershell
~/powershell/pwsh


# Install PWSH on Ubuntu (WSL2/Docker)
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-ubuntu?view=powershell-7.3#installation-via-package-repository
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb"
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y powershell
pwsh
```

I solved problem a with the variable `BASE_IMAGE` that I set override locally, but I'm not sure how to handle b. What's the recommended pattern for this using Docker?

1. Maintain two different `Dockerfile`s (`arm64`/Raspi and `amd64`/Ubuntu/WSL) and swallow the bitter pill of duplicating the first half of the `Dockerfile`.
2. Using some sort of *conditional `RUN` statement* so that there is only only `Dockerfile`, looking like this:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj", "src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/"]
COPY ["src/ScreenshotCreator.Logic/ScreenshotCreator.Logic.csproj", "src/ScreenshotCreator.Logic/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/ScreenshotCreator.Api"
RUN dotnet build "ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ScreenshotCreator.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

if ${PLATFORM}=="arm":
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget libssl1.1 libunwind8
    RUN mkdir -p /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
    RUN wget -O /tmp/powershell.tar.gz https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.6/powershell-7.2.6-linux-arm64.tar.gz
    RUN tar zxf /tmp/powershell.tar.gz -C /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
    RUN chmod +x /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
    RUN ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh
    RUN rm /tmp/powershell.tar.gz
    RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1", "install", "chromium"]
    RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1", "install-deps", "chromium"]
else 
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
    RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y powershell
    RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1" ,"install", "chromium"]
    RUN ["pwsh", "playwright.ps1" ,"install-deps", "chromium"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScreenshotCreator.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: [Question in the Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/platform-specific-run-statements-in-dockerfile/136670)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the Docker forum gave me [this answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/platform-specific-run-statements-in-dockerfile/136670/2?u=mu88) which works like a charm.

Basically there is now a PowerShell installation script for each architecture (`install-powershell-arm64.sh` and `install-powershell-amd64.sh`) and within the `Dockerfile`, it is called like this:

```
ARG TARGETARCH
COPY src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/install-powershell-$TARGETARCH.sh /scripts/install-powershell-$TARGETARCH.sh
RUN chmod +x /scripts/install-powershell-$TARGETARCH.sh
```

[Here's the corresponding commit on GitHub](https://github.com/mu88/ScreenshotCreator/commit/adf35d50a8ceef648c9562e4a618863bfbe50a24).